# Java try-finally race condition?

Tags: java, exception, thread-safety, race-condition

A lot of Java resource usage examples look like this:

```
Resource r = openResource(); 
try { 
  // use resource
} finally { 
  r.close();
}
```

The declaration of `r` has to be outside of the `try`-clause to be visible in the `finally`-clause, but this also makes it look like there's a potential race condition: **what if there's a thread interruption right between the `openResource()`-call and entering the `try`-clause?**

Could that mean that the resource *doesn't* actually get closed in that scenario?

Or does Java guarantee that the `try-finally` covers `r` "fully", despite the syntax looking like it wouldn't?

Or do I have to write:

```
Resource r = null;  
try { 
  r = openResource();
  // use resource
} finally { 
  if (r != null) r.close();
}
```

in order to protect against thread interruptions?

Comment: In theory, yes, there is a problem. In practice, however, so long as there are no intervening statements I doubt that there's a scenario where you could get an interrupt after returning from `openResource` and before entering the `try` region.  The real exposure would be inside `openResource`, which would be before `r` would be set and hence out of the control of the caller anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what if there's a thread interruption right between the openResource()-call and entering the try-clause?

Then the thread won't throw an `InterruptedException` until it hits some blocking call. That can't happen before it gets into the `try` block, because there *aren't* any more blocking calls, assuming the method actually returns. From the docs for [`InterruptedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html):

> Thrown when a thread is waiting, sleeping, or otherwise occupied, and the thread is interrupted, either before or during the activity. Occasionally a method may wish to test whether the current thread has been interrupted, and if so, to immediately throw this exception.

Note that even if you *do* put the acquisition inside the `try` block, that doesn't really prevent any race condition that would otherwise exist - because you'd be relying on the method or constructor returning in the first place. If an exception can happen *after* the method/constructor returns, why can't it happen *just before* it returns, but after the resource has been acquired? If that happens, there's nothing you can call `close` on...

I'd still recommend using the try-with-resources statement in Java 7, but if you look at the [JLS section 14.20.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1) you'll see that the expansion is like your *first* piece of code:

> The meaning of a basic try-with-resources statement:
>
> ```
> try ({VariableModifier} R Identifier = Expression ...)
>     Block
> ```
>
> is given by the following translation to a local variable declaration and a try-catch-finally statement:
>
> ```
> {
>     final {VariableModifierNoFinal} R Identifier = Expression;
>     Throwable #primaryExc = null;
>
>     try ResourceSpecification_tail
>         Block
>     catch (Throwable #t) {
>         ...
>         #primaryExc = #t;
>         throw #t;
>     } finally {
>        ...
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: The term "race condition" is being misapplied here.

Comment: @HotLicks: Actually, I'm not sure it is. If it's one thread calling `interrupt()` on the thread which is handling the resource, the OP believes there's a race between the thread getting interrupted, and it "reaching" the try block.

Comment: Ah, you mean: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html - the exception is only raised when sleeping / waiting, not at arbitrary points.

Comment: The point is that we're only concerned about exceptions, and exceptions are entirely synchronous.  Yes, the *cause* of an exception can be some asynchronous event, but that does not in any way affect how you have to handle the exception.  And, in theory, an InternalError or some such can occur at any point in any Java program, as a result of internal malfunction or the like.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yes, although I'd expect failure to close a resource on an `Error` to be less of a problem. My point is that while we know there's no race condition here, the OP doesn't - they were using the term correctly in terms of asking the question, it's just that the answer is "no".

Answer (score 4):

Those Java resource usage examples could be written like the example you give where `r` is initially set to `null`, but if they used the Java 7 [*try-with-resources*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax (Assuming `Resource` implements [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)):

```
try (Resource r = openResource()) {
    // use resource
}
```

Then they would be equivalent to the first example, where `openResource()` is called prior to the `try` block. The [Java Language Specification for the `try-with-resources` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1) defines the semantics as equivalent to assigning the variable with the initializer before the block, and then entering the `try-catch-finally` block.

There appears to be a problem with an exception occurring before the `try` block is entered. The problem is largely theoretical, though. If `openResource()` returns normally and there are no intervening statements between the assignment to `r` and the beginning of the try block, then it is unlikely, though not impossible, that some other thread would get control before the `try` block began, but even then, when your thread started running again it would enter the `try` block without incident. If the other thread did something that caused the JVM to shut down, such as calling `System.exit`, then you typically would not need to worry about closing resources. And even this case is highly unlikely.

If, on the other hand, there was a problem opening the resource, presumably `openResource()` would throw, which would prevent `r` from ever being assigned.

Comment: I don't believe that's the case - see my answer. Obviously try-with-resources is simpler anyway...

Comment: Also, note that the `try-with-resources` block acquires the resource outside the try/finally too - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1

Comment: I believe that Jon is correct, in this scenario.  But using the try-with-resource style is probably more "structured" and avoids several coding pitfalls.

Comment: @HotLicks: Oh absolutely - I'd always recommend using it. Just not for this reason.

Comment: I've updated to take into account the points made by Hot Licks and QuercusMax. I'll update again to include Jon's link. I wasn't aware of that!

Comment: When you say it's "not impossible" - while the thread may be interrupted in terms of `interrupt()` being called, that's not the same as an exception being thrown.

Comment: I shouldn't have said interrupted. I wasn't thinking about `interrupt()`; rather, I was thinking the thread might be interrupted, and then something bad could happen on another thread causing the JVM to shut down.

Comment: Hmm. Need to think about this. Anyway, my thinking on this is now 180 degrees from when I first started this answer. Thanks to Hot Licks, QuercusMax, and Jon Skeet. I've learned something while writing this answer!

Answer (score 3):

There's no potential race condition. You'd either get an exception during the call to getResource, or it might return null - but there's no race condition. If your thread was interrupted, you may get an InterruptedException, but that would prevent you from entering the **try** block.

Comment: And it should be noted that "race condition" should be reserved for two (or more) threads "simultaneously" accessing/updating the same resource.  In this scenario any exception will be synchronous to the current thread, even if somehow provoked by another thread.